# AlarmManager with ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP not updating PendingIntent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, repeatingalarm

This works without any problems:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getClass().getPackage().getName() + ".ALARM_TRIGGER");

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                BackgroundService.getInstance(),
                mAlarmID,
                mIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pi);
```

The code works. Everytime we run this code, it UPDATES pending intent with the ID (mAlarmID).

However, the code above doesn't trigger if phone is in deep sleep. So we have to use ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP.

```
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + startIn,
            interval,
            pi
    );
```

After checking `adb shell dumpsys alarm`, RTC_WAKEUP always finds and updates correct pending intent. Using alarm manager with ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP however, always creates new pending intent no matter the same id. What does that mean?

- in #1 everytime the code runs, you'll always find only one alarm in dumpsys alarm.
- in #2 everytime the code runs, you'll find ONE MORE alarm in dumpsys alarm.

Is this bug? How then to use this code so you will always have at max 1 alarm?